# Transposing all csv files within a folder

Tags: python, csv

I got help the last time I asked a question on this site regarding batch processing csv files within a folder using `glob.glob()` with Python. I am trying to use it this time to transpose all csv files within a folder. The script below only processes the last file and stops. What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv
import os
import glob

directory = raw_input ("INPUT Folder")
output = raw_input("OUTPUT Folder:")
in_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')

for in_file in glob.glob(in_files):
    with open(in_file) as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        cols = []
        for row in reader:
            cols.append(row)
            filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(in_file))[0] + '.csv'

with open (os.path.join(output, filename), 'wb') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    for i in range(len(max(cols, key=len))):
        writer.writerow ([(c[i] if i<len(c) else '') for c in cols])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to indent the "output" portion of the code so that it runs once for each iteration of the `for in_file` loop:

```
import csv
import os
import glob

directory = raw_input ("INPUT Folder")
output = raw_input("OUTPUT Folder:")
in_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')

for in_file in glob.glob(in_files):
    with open(in_file) as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        cols = []
        for row in reader:
            cols.append(row)

    # "outdent" this code so it only needs to run once for each in_file
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(in_file))[0] + '.csv'

    # Indent this to the same level as the rest of the "for in_file" loop!
    with open (os.path.join(output, filename), 'wb') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        for i in range(len(max(cols, key=len))):
            writer.writerow ([(c[i] if i<len(c) else '') for c in cols])
```

In your version that code only runs once, after the `for in_file` loop has completed, and therefore only outputs `cols` data left over from the final iteration of that loop.

I have also "outdented" the `filename = ...` statement to the `for in_file` level, as this only needs to be done once for each `in_file`, not once for each `row` of each `in_file`.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thank you so much. I didnot realise the improper indentation I was using. Helped me to learn about indentation more. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of mileage with data manipulation using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    # We save an augmented filename later, 
    # so using splitext is useful for more
    # than just checking the extension.
    prefix, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() != '.csv':
        continue
    # Load the data into a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filename, 
                               header=None, 
                               index_col=None, 
                               parse_dates=False)
    # Transpose is easy, but you could do TONS
    # of data processing here. pandas is awesome.
    df_transposed = df.T
    # Save to a new file with an augmented name 
    df_transposed.to_csv(prefix+'_T'+ext, header=True, index=False)
```

The `os.walk` version is not much different, if you need to dig into subfolders as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working one:

had to google for an hour, but works and tested on python33

```
import csv
import os
import glob

directory = 'C:\Python33\csv'
output = 'C:\Python33\csv2'
in_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')

for in_file in glob.glob(in_files):
    with open(in_file) as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        cols = []
        for row in reader:
            cols.append(row)

    # "outdent" this code so it only needs to run once for each in_file
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(in_file))[0] + '.csv'

    # Indent this to the same level as the rest of the "for in_file" loop!
    with open (os.path.join(output, filename), 'w') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        for i in range(len(max(cols, key=len))):
            writer.writerow ([(c[i] if i<len(c) else '') for c in cols])
```

Answer (score -1):

in_files will only return a single result in that format. Try returning a list:

```
in_files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.csv')]
```

Comment: `in_files` is a single string, but the `for in_file` loop iterates over a list of file names that match the glob pattern represented by that string.